# intellij idea не может скачать зависимость javax.servlet.servlet:servlet-api:3.0.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, servlet

intellij idea не может скачать зависимость javax.servlet.servlet:servlet-api:3.0.1
Идет загрузка, потом пропадает, но  зависимость по-прежнему красная.
Я нашел этот jar архив в интернете и скачал. Могу ли я как-то вручную подключить ее?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/lanit/blog/323008/

Comment: @ezhov Спасибо, попробую. Хочу еще кое-что уточнить, дело  в том, что у моего друга те же самые зависимости нормально подгружаются, у меня не все. Не знаете с чем это может быть связано и как это решить?

Comment: Значит у вас настроены разные репозитории. Смотрите сюда `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories`

Comment: @Anton проверили, одинаковые. Добавил скрины

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте вашу зависимость на [эту](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

По поводу подключение просто jar, вы можете в IDEA нажать CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+S или File->Project Structure -> Libraries. 
Там нажать плюсик и указать путь к вашему jar файлу. У вас, скорее всего запросится модуль, к которому вы хотите подключить этот файл, указывайте ваш проект.

[Вот](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html) ссылка на инструкцию

Comment: сделал, не помогло

Comment: У вас используется прокси? Если да, то **File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior ->System Settings ->HTTP Proxy** и поставьте галочку возле Auto-detect proxy settings. Также, проверьте соединение с интернетом через Check connection, чуть ниже

Comment: нет, но вариант с джарником помог, спасибо. И все же, можно что-то еще попробовать, чтобы мавен нормально подгружал зависимости?

Comment: Также, у вас на скрине указано, что вы используете свой (кастомный) Maven, попробуйте использовать встроенный, второй или третьей версии. Когда-нибудь с этим Maven на этом компе что-то грузили? в смысле, он корректно Операционцкой определяется?

Comment: проблема решилась, я добавил путь к джарнику и и зависимость встала. Но дело в том, что у меня не подгружалась еще одна зависимость - maven-archetype-plugin, а сейчас и она подгружается. Скорее всего, проблема была действительно в том, что я использовал кастомный maven(скрин), поменял на Bundled (Maven 3), вроде все норм

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо

Comment: Только что заметил, что на одном уровне с корневым модулем появилась папка lib и в ней 8 джарников javax (servlet,annotation,resource...). Это как-то связано с решением проблемы? Нужна ли она?

Comment: Да, это загрузились библиотеки благодаря jar.

Comment: Извините за назойливость, последнее уточнение, чтобы не бежать в след раз на форум: Я так и не понял что мне помогло, то что я указал путь к джарнику или изменение версии мавена? и нужно ли в будущем скачивать джарники для недостающих бибилотек?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95628/discussion-between-dred-and-artem).

Answer (score 1):

Если работаешь с Maven, то нужно добавлять зависимости в файл pom.xml. Если же хочешь добавить скачанный .jar то Project Structure - Libraries - + - Java - Файл.jar Для Intellij Idea. В Eclipse кажется что то похожее.
Если все равно не подключаются зависимости попробуй Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Build Tools - Maven - включи галочку 'Always update snapshots'. Плюс ответ выше, по поводу репозитория.
Если пользуешься ломанной Intellij Idea, попробуй поставить новую версию.

Comment: спасибо, поставил, не помогло. Репозитории совпадают, только что снес идею и переустановил, тоже самое(

Comment: Попробуйте отключить 'work offline' а также использовать Maven по умолчанию, там идет версия 3.0

Comment: сделал, не помогло

Comment: Не плагин, а сам pom.xml выдает какую то ошибку?

Comment: нет, не выдает. .\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Comment: Омг...  зависимости точно правильно указаны? Потому что если не правильно что то указано, то не будет подтягивать. 
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
Только с servlet проблема? Или еще какие то зависимости не подтягивает?

Comment: проблема решилась, я добавил путь к джарнику и и зависимость встала. Но дело в том, что у меня не подгружалась еще одна зависимость - maven-archetype-plugin, а сейчас и она подгружается. Скорее всего, проблема была в том, что я использовал кастомный maven(скрин), поменял на Bundled (Maven 3), вроде все норм. Еще раз спасибо